# Oracle APEX collections sort by column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to sort and resequence collection using:

```
    APEX_COLLECTION.SORT_MEMBERS(
    p_collection_name => collection name,
    p_sort_on_column_number => column number to sort by);
```

what on earth is this "column number to sort by"? I need to sort it by N001 so what would be the "column number" to pass?

Praveen

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, originally APEX collections only had the VARCHAR2 columns c001 to c050.  Numeric (N001 etc.) and date columns (D001 etc.) were added later.

Unfortunately this procedure only works with the original VARCHAR2 columns, so you cannot sort on column N001.  Hopefully the APEX team will address this in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to clarify.